# Why is str.replace("\\","/") not working?

Tags: python

I wanted to replace them so python can open the file in order to split it, but it doesn't work cause it's giving me the error:

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I'm relatively new to python, but I've seen a lot of sites where they say that this solution works and there's no more code, therefore idk what is wrong with this.

(My goal is to use the separated file to write it on an excel)

```
def separator(filepath):
    files = filepath.replace("\\", "/")
    f=open(files, "r")
    txt = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    print(txt)

separator("C:\Users\Gonza\Coding\Heads or Tails\HeadsTails.txt")
```

SOLUTION: Ok so I solved it and today I figured out it was a good idea to leave this solution here, so what I did was changing:

```
files = filepath.replace("\\", "/")
```

Into this:

```
files = repr(filepath).replace("\\\\","/").replace("\'","")
```

What `repr()` does is transforming the string into a representable version of itself (which I think is the same as r'), with that done `.replace("\\","/")` works perfect but `repr()` also adds quotation marks to it, so I took them out with another `.replace("\'", "")` that way the path is ready to work.

NOTES: I wanted to mention that I only did this cause I wanted to input the path, I'm also sure there's an easier way to do this with the os.path module.

Answer (score 2):

Your function call is

```
separator("C:\Users\Gonza\Coding\Heads or Tails\HeadsTails.txt")
```

The backslashes there are not escaped, so there isn't really a backslash in there.

When you manually input that, you can write an `r` in front of the string

```
separator(r"C:\Users\Gonza\Coding\Heads or Tails\HeadsTails.txt")
```

Which will not apply backslash-escaping.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but is there any way I can input that into the terminal? Cause if I do it, it tells me that it is an invalid argument.

Comment: .@GonzaloMartín That happens when you don't write the `r` in front of the string. When you write \U in a string, it tries to read the following 8 characters as a hexadecimal number of a Unicode symbol. Either you escape your backslashes `\\ ` or you put the `r` at the beginning, which will tell python to take this text raw and don't resolve escaped characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw string for input: https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-raw-strings

```
separator(r"C:\Users\Gonza\Coding\Heads or Tails\HeadsTails.txt")
```

Note the "r" before the string

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, at least when I put it into my IDE, the input string is escaping the slashes instead of keeping them as is. "\" Escapes the next character in a regular string.